# executing .run file unsuccesful in arch linux

Tags: arch-linux

```
[theoranger@archlinux ~]$ ls
Descargas  Desktop  Downloads  from_the_depths_v3.4.1.17.run  my_summer_car_v10.01.2022.run
[theoranger@archlinux ~]$ chmod +x from_the_depths_v3.4.1.17.run 
[theoranger@archlinux ~]$ ./from_the_depths_v3.4.1.17.run 

  YAD Simple Installer (21.12.2021): From the Depths (3.4.1.17)

[theoranger@archlinux ~]$ uname -a from_the_depths_v3.4.1.17.run 
uname: operando extra «from_the_depths_v3.4.1.17.run»
Pruebe 'uname --help' para más información.
[theoranger@archlinux ~]$ file from_the_depths_v3.4.1.17.run 
from_the_depths_v3.4.1.17.run: a /usr/bin/env sh script executable (binary data)
[theoranger@archlinux ~]$
```

I've been succesful in running this file in Pop_OS, this does not happen in arch linux, a GUI is supposed to pop up and this doesn't happen. I have tried running chmod +x x.run (x being the file name) and running it in the terminal gives me nothing, running it in the file manager doesn't execute the file, rather it opens it in the default text editor (mind you i double checked that the file had permission to execute) I also tried running it in the Desktop and also didn't work. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is the .run file a shell script with binary data? What programs does the script call? Is yad installed?

Comment: The .run file is a shell script with binary data, I believe that the script calls yad simple installer, and yad is installed.